# mongodb query aggregate can't read this._id with the value of id which want to aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

this is my query for aggregation for organization, person, and transactions

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "organizations",
            localField: "organization",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "or",
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "people",
            localField: "person",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "person",
        },
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$person"
    },
    { $group:
            {
                _id: "$_id",
                p: {
                    $first: "$person._id"
                },
                or: {
                    $first: {
                        $arrayElemAt: [
                            "$or.members",
                            0,
                        ]
                    }
                },
            }
    },
    {
       $project: {
           out: {
               $filter: {
                   input: "$or",
                   cond: {
                       $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$person._id"]
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
])
```

the `or.member` value is array like this :

```
[
 {
  "accessLevel": "organization_admin", 
  "title": "CTO", "_id": ObjectId("5f130f357907baf4dc919816"), 
  "status": true
 }
]
```

and the transactions collection like this:

```
// transaction
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c97")
  organization: ObjectId("5f127ce1e354f37df698f55e")
  person: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c95")
  actionTransaction: "Purchase"
}

// organizations
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f127ce1e354f37df698f55e")
  name:  "MongoDB Inc"
  phoneNumber: "+1111111111"
  members: [
              {
                  _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c95")
                  title: "CEO"
                  role: "ADMIN"
              },
              {
                  _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7ff8a6b9300d93")
                  title: "CHAIRMAN"
                  role: "Others"
              }
          ]
}

// people 
{
   _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c95")
   name: "Foo Bar"
   gender: "Male"
}
```

when I query with string by other field in organization.member, it looks fine, but when I query with id, it always empty array result
is that something wrong?*emphasized text*

Comment: Its clear that both object id's are not same. Correct? Person has different one and or.member has different one.

Comment: I think there is some `person` I deleted on database, so maybe some person got null, 
I want to filter the `organization.member` which same like `person` in transaction, so when I query transaction I dont get all member showing :D @Gibbs

Comment: Can you add sample data which is reproducible your issue? So that anyone can help you.

Comment: I just updated @Gibbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `$group` to set `p` as the following

```
                p: {
                    $first: "$person._id"
                },
```

So in the last stage, there is no `$person._id` anymore, there is only `p`, you should change `$person._id` to `$p`

```
    {
       $project: {
           out: {
               $filter: {
                   input: "$or",
                   cond: {
                       $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$p"]
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: it still return null in my database

Comment: Maybe you already changed some of your code? Check [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tju1AYkMErk)

Comment: I dont', in my mongodb local, it doesn't work though I tried it here also https://mongoplayground.net/p/rFeV3NTwQsX

Comment: What's your MongoDB version?

Comment: 4.2.8 mongo atlas

Comment: organization.member might empty array as well possible, would it effect ?

Comment: If it's an empty array then it would output also the empty array for `out`, that's your logic, right? because you would be filtering an empty array

Comment: yess, but it got empty in my local, and I have no idea what's wrong with my syntax :(

Comment: I'm confused now, what do you expect to get if `organization.member` is empty?

Comment: I meant, why the `out` field in mine always return empty array? did u know?